# What does the Advanced OpenGL setting in the video settings of Minecraft do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was looking through the Minecraft settings and saw this. I tried the setting, but it seems that there is no difference at all(see below).
[image: the settings]

**Before:**
[image: before advanced opengl]

**After:**
[image: after advanced opengl]

So what does this do to Minecraft, and does it help in performance, etc. or makes it slower?

Comment: Whether it has an effect depends on whether your graphics card supports it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is *supposed* to improve the framerate and general performance of the game on some video cards.

However, as you (and [others](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1020&t=295169)) have noticed it really doesn't do much sometimes. For others it does help, and some [people](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=298778) have even seen a performance drop with it.

Comment: *How* it's supposed to do this is by implementing [occlusion culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occlusion_culling#Occlusion_culling). This makes the GPU render fewer objects but requires the CPU to do a few more calculations in order to figure out what to have the GPU not draw. So whether it helps or hinders depends on whether that's a good or a bad trade-off for your particular system.

Answer (score 0):

I play Minecraft on my Mac when I’m away from home. I turned it on and it runs as smooth as butter now. When playing normal Minecraft, runs fine anyway, but I play Attack of the B-Team and it sits around 20-30, turned this on and now I have perfect 60 all the time.

Answer (score -3):

Advanced OpenGL basically helps with some cpus and decreases fps on some cpus

Answer (score -4):

OpenGL basically improves the performance of the game and the behaviour to more normal.

So that means advanced will improve them both x2!

Comment: This question has already been answered.  Unless you have anything better to contribute to answer, please just leave it alone.

You should **never** really answer a question that has been marked as solver (The green tick by an answer) unless you have something new or useful to assist them with, however still only if you think it may be relevant at the later time.

Comment: Neither of those sentences are right.